# Errors building Monodevelop with VS14

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, mono

I've been trying to build MonoDevelop (not Xamarin Studio). These are the steps I've taken:

1. Installed VS 2015 community. Standard install but w/o web dev stuff
2. Installed GTK# 2.12.26 from [mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win) and added `GtkSharp\2.12\bin` to the `PATH`
3. Installed the Mono libraries from [monodevelop.com](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/) and added `MonoLibraries\2.6` to the `PATH`
4. Installed Gettext from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm) and added `GnuWin32\bin` to the `PATH`
5. Downloaded and extracted MonoDevelop 5.10.0.704 tar from [mono-project.com](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/)
6. Opened `monodevelop-5.10\Main.sln` in VS and selected the `DebugWin32` configuration
7. Built Solution and promptly got ~20,000 errors which you can see in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2bdkid/fa05219daf3c2f38dd57)

It's obvious that it can't find namespaces but I don't understand C# enough to make use of these build errors, though I think it's because I installed the dependency libraries wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That project is not built with VS. So if you do want to use VS you will have to learn every bits. Not very likely that many people attempt to do so.

Comment: Some of the build errors seem to be due to bad solution/project configuration. It should not be compiling anything to do with Xwt.Mac on Windows. You can build monodevelop on Windows using the winbuild.bat file instead.

Comment: Once I get around to it I'll try winbuild.bat and post the results

Comment: Ok I had to clone from github.com/mono/monodevelop. I checkout out monodevelop-5.10.0.704 and updated all the submodules. winbuild.bat gives me these errors: https://gist.github.com/2bdkid/dfa2585877632912508a

Comment: Ok I fixed the last error by installing the Windows 8 SDK but there are still errors. https://gist.github.com/2bdkid/786797e89e80259b83df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've managed to build it with the help if MonoDevelop's [Gitter](https://gitter.im/mono/monodevelop)

This is what I've done since:

1. Install Mono from [mono-project.com](http://mono-project.com) and add `Mono\bin` to the `PATH`
2. Installed the MSBuild 2013 tools from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760)
3. Cloned from github.com/mono/monodevelop and ran `main\winbuid.bat`

Everything seems to work now!